# Jupyter Notebookでどうしても分からないところがあります

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Pythonを最近学び始めた学生です。どうしても分からないところがあるので、皆様のお力を貸していただけるとありがたいです。

形態素解析の勉強をしており、Jupyter Notebook上でトークナイザーを生成するため、参考書に載っていたコードをそのまま実行したところ、エラーが出てしまいました。
どこが間違っているのかを指摘して頂けるとありがたいです。

なお、Janomeは仮想環境でインストール済みです。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'janome'
```

**実行したコード**

```
from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer

t = Tokenizer()
t
```

Comment: もう少し細かい環境や手順の情報が必要でしょうが、こんなところでは？[jupyter notebookで、なぜかimportが通らない問題](https://qiita.com/verdy89/items/14b232d1bdb474bd6fc9), [【同居人からの質問】pipでインストールしたのにjupyter notebookでパッケージがimport出来ない問題](https://note.com/hanawa11ify/n/n8b7f5eb28dcb), [【python】ImportError: No module named '***'の対処法](https://www.haya-programming.com/entry/2018/09/09/202711), [pythonでImportError: No module named ・・・が出たときの確認方法と対処](https://web.plus-idea.net/2017/05/python-import-error-no-module-name/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既に解決済みかもしれませんが、おそらく同じ本で同じトラブルに合い解決できたので参考にまで。インストールしたjanomeをフォルダーごとコピーし、AnacondaのLibの中にペーストしたらできました。

Answer (score 0):

インストールしたjanomeをフォルダーごとコピーし、AnacondaのLibの中にペーストしたらできると思います。